# How to preprocess an ld linker script?

Tags: c, linker, c-preprocessor, ld

I was digging into the art of linkage scripting when I crossed the sources of the [L4 Pistachio micro-kernel](https://github.com/l4ka/pistachio/tree/c775191a0d004eb761e594ed6ea3aacccf6c7d33). What hurts me is how **C** preprocessor syntax is used in linker scripts, [here for example](https://github.com/l4ka/pistachio/blob/c775191a0d004eb761e594ed6ea3aacccf6c7d33/kernel/src/glue/v4-x86/x64/linker.lds) (line 35)!

```
[...]

#include INC_GLUE_SA(offsets.h)

[...]
```

I find no documentation about it nowhere, and I have answers like "this is not possible". But I think it's there because it's usable anyhow... But HOW?
I obviously tried something like "gcc -E", didn't work.

As this possibility looks interesting to me, do you have any information about this?

Comment: Looks like `INC_GLUE_SA` is defined as `#define INC_GLUE_SA(x) <glue/__API__-__ARCH__/__SUBARCH__/x>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the Makefiles for the Pistachio kernel [runs the `.lds` file through `cpp`](https://github.com/l4ka/pistachio/blob/c775191a0d004eb761e594ed6ea3aacccf6c7d33/kernel/Mk/Makeconf#L252-253) to generate the final linker script (as `lds.tmp`).

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are correct about using the C preprocessor - at least for this project.  `kernel/Mk/Makeconf` contains the following rule:

```
#.INTERMEDIATE: lds.tmp
    lds.tmp: $(LDSCRIPT) $(SRCDIR)/Mk/Makeconf $(SRCDIR)/src/generic/macros.h $(BUILDDIR)/config/config.h
    @$(CPP) -DASSEMBLY $(PPFLAGS) -P -C $< -o $@
```

Comment: Yes, thank you ! It was too much obvious that $(CPP) was actually the "cpp" (like C PreProcessor) command instead of "c++" as I though. The "-P" works just fine ! it's very interesting to me :) thank you